# Unity3D 5.3.1 Mac Installation failure

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, download, assistant

I'm trying to install Unity 3D V 5.3.1 on my Mac. I was able to download the UnityDownloadAssistant.dmg file, however when I run the installer, it fails [Download Assistant Failure Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YassT.png). Please see the screenshot.

I've been stuck on this for the last 10 days, I've tried with different network connections as well. I went ahead and checked their old downloads as suggested by some other people on the internet. But all their old links are broken.

Anyone else come across this issue and any solutions please??

Comment: Weird the screenshot says it is trying to download Unity 5.2.4 not 5.3.1, maybe try the newest patch release.

Comment: Actually, I did try 5.3.1 and then tried downloading an older installer file (V5.2.4). And I just posted 5.2.4 error screenshot, but it's just exactly the same even with a newer installer file, except that they say they're not able to find the newer files.

Comment: The download assistant keeps failing but you can click on 'Retry' again and again to continue downloading even though it keeps failing.  That looks like some time out issue. But finally I wasn't able to download all components this way. I gave up and downloaded 5.3.0 version from the torrents pointed to on the download link. Now encountering several other errors when exporting the app to an iOS App, but the original failure solution or work around is that go and download from the torrents.